# Solute with the Horner method (4x^3-x^2+5x-6):(3x+9)

Tags: polynomials

```
4   -1  5   -6
```

2       8   14  +38
    4   7   19  4 4
But the Q(x) should be 2x2+7/2x+19/2 with a remainder of 32 if we divide it normally. Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{(4x^3-x^2+5x-6)}{3x+9}=\frac{4x^2-13x+44}{3}\times(3x+9)-138$$

Using Horner's Method
also we get same answer. (I can't point out mistake in your calculations as it is hardly readable)